# How to run multiple Celery daemons for each Vhost

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

How do you setup a Celery daemon so it executes tasks for multiple separate Django sites?

I have several separate Django sites running on the same host, and I want to support Celery-powered asynchronous tasks for each site. Celery (specifically with the RabbitMQ backend) supports grouping tasks via the BROKER_VHOST settings parameter, but I'm unclear how to setup the daemon to properly execute tasks for all vhosts.

I'm planning on setting up an init daemon, according to the [docs](http://ask.github.io/celery/cookbook/daemonizing.html), but the Celeryd configuration file only allows you to specify a single Django settings file. If I'm understanding this correctly, will I have to setup a separate Celery daemon for each unique Django settings file? Or is there some way to configure Celeryd to work with all Django sites?

Comment: Not sure about how to run celery separately for each vhost, But one thing you can do is that you can define routes for each of your tasks. So each task will have its separate Queue. See [routing tasks](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html).

Comment: @AamirAdnan, I don't see how routes/queues applies to me. As far as I can tell from those docs, all queues would be executed with the same Django settings...

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to figure out how to setup celery daemons for multiple servers (each with its own database) as well. Here are the references I found. Neither give a complete answer, but there might be some inspiration available to help you figure it out.

- [Using celeryd as a daemon with multiple django apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10234386/using-celeryd-as-a-daemon-with-multiple-django-apps)
- https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/celery-users/pM7B-VO_PUQ